# Difficulty with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current plan: making the button with the white circle around, does not even need the WhatsApp icon.

[image]

But after so much hitting my head and looking for a solution, I could not find the solution and came for help. 
It's coming out like this:

[image]

Someone can help me?

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="keywords" content="piauí fábio abreu segurança eleições">
        <title>Fábio Abreu</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Fábio Abreu">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Fábio Abreu">
        <meta name="description" content="Site do deputado federal e secretário de segurança do estado do Piauí, Fábio Abreu.">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Site do deputado federal e secretário de segurança do estado do Piauí, Fábio Abreu.">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Site do deputado federal e secretário de segurança do estado do Piauí, Fábio Abreu."> 

        <meta property="og:image" content="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png">
        <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png">

        <meta property="og:image:width" content="600">

        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Fábio Abreu">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fabioabreupi.com.br/">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">

<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="smUoPpsSNtD2udIYqosIhQyHKaWY5tK49rUhJBLTElTKMCyIgbxE3BAqVwLvADny/9UZ+J6IGf29QvjPM72Fvw==" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/site-dc393f9cdad26bd31342ace6c0e567e3893492c1ec06c16976bea61958ce06ad.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/default/css/main-5c3e617fe669fbfd1915fd6ba42ddae97daaf842e3037fde45d55bfdd0f7b4aa.css" />

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.fabioabreupi.com.br/">

<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/original_95e76849-329a-449b-8e1b-f118083035a4.png' /> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto Condensed:400,400i,700,700i' rel='stylesheet'>   <style>


            #TopMenu ul#menu-main li a,#TopMenu ul#menu-main li a span.caret{font-size:14px !important;text-transform:uppercase !important}
            #MainHeader{background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important}
            h3{font-size:15px !important;font-family:'Roboto Condensed' !important;font-weight:bold !important}

            footer#MainFooter{background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;border-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important}
    </style>

<style>#TopMenu{
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2722ad+28,ff3b21+100 */
background: #2722ad; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2722ad 28%, #ff3b21 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2722ad 28%,#ff3b21 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #2722ad 28%,#ff3b21 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2722ad', endColorstr='#ff3b21',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#menu-main{
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 9px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 9px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

#menu-main li:last-child{
  padding-left: 178px;
}

#menu-main li:last-child{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #bfb9bf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #bfb9bf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#bfb9bf');
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 42px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000000;
    height:35px;
    line-height:26px;
    width:178px
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 6px #ffffff;
}
.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #bfb9bf), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #bfb9bf 5%, #f9f9f9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#bfb9bf', endColorstr='#f9f9f9');
    background-color:#bfb9bf;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:44px;
}


}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(2){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(3){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(4){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu-main li:nth-last-child(5){
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#MainHeader{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px; 
}

#MainFooter{
 background-color: #00004d 
}

#GroupList1{
 background-color: #ffffff; 
 box-shadow: none;
}

#lws-homesection-title{
  text-align: center;
}

#GroupList2{
 display: none; 
}</style>
</head>

<body class="palette-red">


    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <header id="MainHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row vertical-align">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <div class="LogoArea">
                        <a href="/" id="BrandImage">
                            <img src="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_caecb618-6523-409d-8af6-d31dbd7351b0.png" alt="Fábio Abreu" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div id="ContactsTop">


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<nav id="TopMenu" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn">
          <li><a href="/" target="">Início</a></li>
              <li><a href="/categories/noticias">NOTÍCIAS</a></li>

              <li><a href="/categories/fotos">FOTOS</a></li>

              <li><a href="/categories/projetos">PROJETOS</a></li>

              <li><a href="/biografia">BIOGRAFIA</a></li>

              <li><a href="www.whatsapp.com.br">ENTRE EM CONTATO</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="mySlide">
    <div style="width:100%;" id="bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" class="inner-content-slide carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000" data-pause="hover"><ol class="carousel-indicators"><li data-target="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li><li data-target="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li><li data-target="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li></ol><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"><div class="item active"><div data-img-height="481" data-img-width="1000" class="item-img" role="img" aria-label="" style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_f5a4a97f-204c-4538-bc79-d4bed4be75f3.jpeg);background-size:cover"></div></div><div class="item "><div data-img-height="480" data-img-width="1000" class="item-img" role="img" aria-label="" style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_06fa6929-4e05-4d40-aebd-99233e3852d6.JPG);background-size:cover"></div></div><div class="item "><div data-img-height="488" data-img-width="1000" class="item-img" role="img" aria-label="" style="height:500px;background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_471118d4-7857-496c-b0db-21d5479de784.jpg);background-size:cover"></div></div></div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-prev"></i><span class="sr-only">Anterior</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#bf494d0c-d537-4f36-bdf2-4754dbee0839" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-next"></i><span class="sr-only">Próximo</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="marketing">
    <div class="container"><section data-section-area='V10'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='V10' data-section-id='c60fb099-5b76-4835-a254-f7ead8bde197'><div class='lws-homesection-text-image'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6'><img src='https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_edab1478-6055-4a29-aa01-1fe4426e6ff2.png' class='img-responsive'></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6'><div class='lws-homesection-body'>Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauí em 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire. Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauí em 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire.
Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauíem 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire.
Ingressou na Polícia Militar do Piauí em 1993 e possui especialização em Segurança Pública pela Universidade Estadual do Piauíem 2013. Ao tempo de sua eleição como deputado federal pelo PTB em 2014, ostentava a patente de capitão. Licenciou-se do mandato no terceiro governo Wellington Dias para assumir a Secretaria de Segurança Pública sendo convocado o suplente Silas Freire.</div></div></div></div></div></section></div>

    <div id="GroupList1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div data-iw-group="group1">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_6310756a-7f23-4ba3-bedb-2b317c786ed3.png); background-size: cover" data-iw-bg="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_6310756a-7f23-4ba3-bedb-2b317c786ed3.png" data-iw-image="image_group1"  data-iw-version="medium" class="area-img"> </div>
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group1">Projetos</h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group1"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group1" class=" btn btn-primary" href="categories/projetos" role="button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div data-iw-group="group2">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_b665fc4e-f95d-4b91-9dea-138d5b287022.png); background-size: cover" data-iw-bg="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_b665fc4e-f95d-4b91-9dea-138d5b287022.png" data-iw-image="image_group2" data-iw-version="medium" class="area-img"> </div>
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group2">Biografia</h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group2"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group2" class=" btn btn-primary" href="biografia" role="button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div data-iw-group="group3">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_08c91774-9593-498f-b984-e4ac21991226.png); background-size: cover" data-iw-bg="https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/large_08c91774-9593-498f-b984-e4ac21991226.png" data-iw-image="image_group3" data-iw-version="medium" class="area-img"> </div>
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group3">Fotos</h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group3"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group3" class=" btn btn-primary" href="categories/fotos" role="button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><section data-section-area='V20'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='V20' data-section-id='a40ab6b2-e909-4021-99b5-ac1ebde763d7'><h2 class='lws-homesection-title'>Notícias destaque</h2><div class='lws-homesection-resource-list'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><div class='lws-homesection-wrapper-item'><div role='img' aria-label='' class='resource-list-post-thumbnail' style='background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_dc88125b-b8f3-4455-bcbc-de7d9d0720ca.jpg);background-size:cover'></div><h4 class='resource-list-title'>Fábio Abreu troca PTB pelo PR e tenta reeleição a deputado federal</h4><div class='resource-list-excerpt'>No evento de filiação ao PR, Fábio Abreu anunciou sua pré-candidatura a deputado federal e afirmou que está preparado para disputar a reeleição. O ...</div><a href='/posts/fabio-abreu-troca-ptb-pelo-pr-e-tenta-reeleicao-a-deputado-federal' class='btn btn-primary'>Veja mais</a></div></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><div class='lws-homesection-wrapper-item'><div role='img' aria-label='' class='resource-list-post-thumbnail' style='background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_d445acdc-1a7f-4b75-a96c-76f3e0cf67d3.jpg);background-size:cover'></div><h4 class='resource-list-title'>Antes de entregar cargo, Fábio Abreu apresenta Plano de Segurança</h4><div class='resource-list-excerpt'>
O documento traça uma linha de trabalho para o setor pelos próximoa s20 anos e prevê investimentos que começam com um empréstimo junto ao BNDES p...</div><a href='/posts/antes-de-entregar-cargo-fabio-abreu-apresenta-plano-de-seguranca' class='btn btn-primary'>Veja mais</a></div></div><div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg"></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><div class='lws-homesection-wrapper-item'><div role='img' aria-label='' class='resource-list-post-thumbnail' style='background-image:url(https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/medium_56e67980-ecd2-444e-a0d9-e2c8a8735420.jpg);background-size:cover'></div><h4 class='resource-list-title'>Fábio Abreu destaca falta de atenção a segurança pública</h4><div class='resource-list-excerpt'>
Em entrevista ao Acorda Piauí, o deputado federal Fábio Abreu (PR), destacou que, enquanto a falta de segurança pública é um dos problemas mais a...</div><a href='/posts/fabio-abreu-destaca-falta-de-atencao-a-seguranca-publica' class='btn btn-primary'>Veja mais</a></div></div><div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12 col-lg-12"></div></div></div></div></section></div>

    <div id="GroupList2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="GL2-item" data-iw-group="group4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group4" class="featurette-heading"></h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group4" class="lead"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group4" class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif); background-size: cover" data-iw-image="image_group4" data-iw-version="medium"data-iw-bg="/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif" class="imagem-topicos"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="GL2-item" data-iw-group="group5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group5" class="featurette-heading"></h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group5" class="lead"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group5" class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif); background-size: cover" data-iw-image="image_group5" data-iw-version="medium"data-iw-bg="/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif" class="imagem-topicos"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="GL2-item" data-iw-group="group6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2 data-iw-line="title_group6" class="featurette-heading"></h2>
                        <p data-iw-multiline="body_group6" class="lead"></p>
                        <a data-iw-link="link_group6" class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div role="img" aria-label="" style="background-image: url(/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif); background-size: cover" data-iw-image="image_group6" data-iw-version="medium"data-iw-bg="/assets/no-pixel-d69f97510d506fdff62059b955a572bfebc93e9c0a243ec79beaf245e737b59a.gif" class="imagem-topicos"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><section data-section-area='V30'></section></div>
</div>

<footer id="MainFooter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="lws-home-sections-footer">
            <div class="lws-1-col-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><section data-section-area='F10'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='F10' data-section-id='f97be27b-c0e9-4229-b584-64ee920ef08a'><img src='https://inovaweb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/image/original_3939ae3f-43d1-4f63-a724-741c5ae11f47.png' class='img-responsive'></div></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-2-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F20'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F30'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-4-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F40'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F50'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F60'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F70'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <ul class="contacts_footer list-inline">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>

                <p>© 2018 - Fábio Abreu</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="lws-home-sections-footer">
            <div class="lws-1-col-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><section data-section-area='F80'><div data-section='home-section' data-area='F80' data-section-id='76c13c4e-249f-4cac-b9ae-e2a56220e80c'><div class='lws-homesection-body'>Todos os direitos reservados.
</div></div></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-2-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F90'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><section data-section-area='F100'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lws-4-cols-footer lws-cols-footer-hs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F110'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F120'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F130'></section></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><section data-section-area='F140'></section></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>


    <script src="/assets/site-fd70af901fb20b8029f75be40e0f5ff5848d5415b704279fd88ad5bc9c0ec4ec.js"></script>

    <script src="/assets/default/js/main-efff309d3722bafb3f5fa5a2092f366e799cac0d724996ca31c7e52b408475ec.js"></script>




        <div id="side-social-networks-loguei" role="group" class="list-unstyled btn-group-vertical">
    </div>



    <aside id="AVS-ContactButtons" class="">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">



    </ul>
</aside>

<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#AVS-ContactButtons ul li a span').css({
            right: '-200px'
        });
    }, 4000);
</script>



    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '1982872918652221',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.11'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.onload = function() { fbAsyncInit(); }
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=1982872918652221';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var NEWSLETTER_URL = '/fabio-abreu-1/newsletters';

        var DEFAULT_ADDRESS = '';

        $('.iw-contact-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();var f = $(this);$.ajax({
                url:'/contact/fabio-abreu-1?authenticity_token=%2FLURz%2Fx9fdgyLq2zjSHViEkAz%2BQpMcS5Jvvnqwx9hveE4BV55tMP1NS9KKnIquT%2FulL%2FuS9fD%2FxtDD5ALRMRHA%3D%3D',
                type:'POST',data:f.serialize(),success:function(){
                    var redir = $('#iw_redir_loguei_cf').length;
                    if (redir == 0) {alert('Email enviado com sucesso');f[0].reset();} else {
                        var to = $('#iw_redir_loguei_cf').val(); window.location=to;
                    }
                },error:function(){alert('Erro ao enviar email');}
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
#menu-main li:last-child{
  padding-left: 378px;
}

#menu-main li:last-child{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #bfb9bf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #bfb9bf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#bfb9bf');
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border-top-left-radius:42px;
    border-radius-topleft:42px;
    border-top-left-radius:42px;
    border-top-right-radius:42px;
    border-radius-topright:42px;
    border-top-right-radius:42px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    border-radius-bottomright:42px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:42px;
    border-radius-bottomleft:42px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:42px;
    text-indent:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000000;
    height:35px;
    line-height:26px;
    width:178px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 6px #ffffff;
}
.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #bfb9bf), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #bfb9bf 5%, #f9f9f9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#bfb9bf', endColorstr='#f9f9f9');
    background-color:#bfb9bf;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: The box don't move with the text.

Comment: what are all these borders ??

Comment: I was defining each border alone, instead of using "border-radius: 42px"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be happy to help, but I would need to see your HTML, so please add it to the question.

I imagine that:

1. It has too much width
2. You probably need some margin around it to make it centered more on the navbar
3. That `padding-left: 378px;` should likely be margin-left or nothing, as that might be causing the over-sided width

Also, if you want the WhatsApp icon you can check out https://fontawesome.com/icons/whatsapp?style=brands

Comment: Hey, Kieran. Thank you. I was able to change this width question, instead of using the padding-left, I used a margin-left. Now the problem is with the centralization of the name inside the button, it's getting like there's a margin above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "like a margin above"? (There is a `margin-top: 1px` on that button, is that what you mean?) I am sure your code works but it is not being nice with any jsfiddle I try to make, so it is hard for me to test it myself.

Answer (score -1):

You can just set `border-radius: 42px;` instead of doing each corner by itself.

try using `float: right;` on the button and I think you were trying to use `margin-left` and not `padding-left` on `#menu-main li:last-child`

Comment: This is what I want: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/544/356/full/2.JPG?1533329815


This is the result:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/544/358/full/1.JPG?1533329839